# Why right side of desktop isn't stop pointer?

Tags: 18.04, screen

I'm a new user to the Ubuntu community. I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.
Every time I try to move my mouse to the right of the screen, my mouse doesn't stop at the end of the screen, but it's getting lost, like there is an extension of my screen that I can't see. The same thing happens if I try to move a windows to the right, outside my screen's barrier.

Does anyone know why it's happening and how may I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is not quite standard, because by default, Ubuntu 18.04 will do "Edge Tiling". If you drag a window to left, right or bottom edges, at some point the system will show a coloured outline, suggesting that the window will be tiled if you release the button.

This feature can be enabled/disabled using Gnome Tweaks. Gnome Tweaks is not installed by default in Ubuntu, so you may need to install it first. You will find that option on the "Windows" tab.

With the feature disabled, I find I cannot move the mouse pointer past the edge of the screen. Maybe, you have a dual monitor setup. In that case, you can continue dragging past an edge to the second screen.

If you have a dual (or triple) monitor setup, you can configure the layout in Settings - Displays. It is, however, not possible to have a second screen act as an independent workspace (unfortunatelly). This, your second screen will always be adjacent your current screen (depending where you place it to the right, above or to the left. So in that direction, you always will be able to drag, and you cannot prevent that.